# Plotly line chart with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, charts, plotly

How can I pass data from MVC controller to AJAX call in Plotly recommended chart data format?

I need data in the below format for multiple line series in javascript

```
var trace2 = {
    x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
    y: [3, 10, 17, 18],
    type: 'scatter'
};
```

**Current attempt**

I have taken data from a Data table and could format it to JSON string (the closest I could for the data for plotly line chart) as below:

```
{
  "trace1": {
    "name": "trace1",
    "x": [ "30/6/2017 11:40:38", "30/6/2017 11:40:38", "30/6/2017 11:40:38", "30/6/2017 11:40:38" ],
    "y": [ 10.0, 12.0, 95.0, 99.0 ]
  },
  "trace2": {
    "name": "trace2",
    "x": [ "30/6/2017 11:40:38", "30/6/2017 11:40:38", "30/6/2017 11:40:38", "30/6/2017 11:40:38" ],
    "y": [ 10.0, 12.0, 95.0, 99.0 ]
  }
}
```

Now I am sending this in JSON format to AJAX success method using the below return

```
string jsonString= "{\"trace1\":{\"name\":\"trace1\",\"x\":[\"30/6/2017 11:32:55\",\"30/6/2017 11:32:55\",\"30/6/2017 11:32:55\",\"30/6/2017 11:32:55\"],\"y\":[10.0,12.0,95.0,99.0]},\"trace2\":{\"name\":\"trace2\",\"x\":[\"30/6/2017 11:32:55\",\"30/6/2017 11:32:55\",\"30/6/2017 11:32:55\",\"30/6/2017 11:32:55\"],\"y\":[10.0,12.0,95.0,99.0]}}";
return new JsonResult { Data = jsonString, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

I need to format this into plotly accepted format for line traces.

Comment: Create a view model with properties `IEnumerable<int> x`, `IEnumerable<int> y` and `string type`

Comment: Could you please elaborate with an example? I'm new to C#.Net

Comment: You have not given nearly enough information. How do you want to get this object - by passing a model to the view and converting it to a javascript object, by calling an ajax function that returns a `JsonResult`? Show how you call and use this data.

Comment: Now its really confusing - in the first snippet, `x` is an array of `int`, not `DateTime` and `y` is a array of `int`, not `double` and there no `name` property, but there is a `type` property. And what is `dsYieldJsonString`? And you still have not shown how you call or use the data

Comment: I've updated the code snippet. There are differences I agree. But the second snippet is the one I could get closest to formatting my data source . I need to plot date on x-axis and percentage on y-axis.

Comment: So why have you said you need the data in the format shown by the first snippet? And why are you building a `string` - you should be returning and model containing the data you want.

Comment: I may be wrong with my approach in this case. I would edit my question to reflect the about the chart details. Did you mean returning the DataTable itself rather than string?

Comment: No,I mean create a view model representing the data you want - which I noted in my first comment.

Comment: Got your point. Could you please help me with a sample code for the approach for this?

Comment: I gave you that in my first comment. I cannot give any more based on the unclear and confusing question.